# Словник чи збірка звуконаслідувань

Tags: resource-request, ономатопея

Чи є словник чи значна збірка українських звуконаслідувань, ще відоме як [ономатопея](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%8F)?

Ось наприклад для [японської](http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/about/) з перекладом чи поясненням анґлійською з прикладами. [Анґлійська Вікі](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias) має відносно маленького підбору ріжних мов, де українська не всюди, що більше схоже на приклад.

Comment: Знајшов декотру добірку в [Норми української літературної мови,  § 96. Розряди вигуків
(О. Синявський)](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_nevidm), але вже без појаснень і досьі прикладами, тобто не повноцьіна збірка.

Comment: Шче одна [добірка](https://raphnana.livejournal.com/132807.html).

Comment: [Тут](https://ukurainajin.dreamwidth.org/228814.html) шчось јесть троʼ: Јапонсько-Украјинсјкиј, заувага, же таких словників немаʼ.